# How to generate expanded list from two short list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists, one for attributes the other for statistics:

```py
l1 = ['speed', 'accel']
l2 = ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'std']
```

I want to generate this expanded list of attributes' statistics:

```py
l3 = ['speed_min', 'speed_max', 'speed_mean', 'speed_std', 'accel_min', 'accel_max', 'accel_mean', 'accel_std']
```

In that order.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the code you're struggling with

Comment: What is the data type of these list elements? As you coded it now, they are *names* (variables, native functions, ...). Did you forget quotes?

Comment: @trincot Neither *min* nor *max* are variables

Comment: my bad, I should have copied and pasted the code instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your desired output it will be like this:

```
resultList = list()
l1 = ['speed', 'accel']
l2 = ['min', 'max', 'mean', 'std']

for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        resultList.append(i+'_'+j)
print(resultList)
```